C# compiler fails to error when it should
The compiler fails to detect that line 3 will error:
IList<IList<double>> xs = new List<IList<double>> { new List<double> { 2 } };
IList<string> x0 = xs.First();      // does not compile, as expected
foreach (IList<string> x in xs) { } // works, unexpectedly!

(Even though there's no error, Visual Studio does suggest on line 3 that there is an implicit cast, which may fail at runtime.)
Interestingly, the compiler successfully detects the issue here:
IList<double> xs = new List<double> { 2 };
string x0 = xs.First();      // does not compile, as expected
foreach (string x in xs) { } // also does not compile, as expected

Is there a good reason why line 3 just gives a suggestion and not an error, like in lines 2, 5, and 6?

As to why it does this, it does this since before generic collections (e.g. List<T>) and var existed, then you would be using something like ArrayList - this syntax made iterating over that type possible. If this syntax wasn't allowed, then strongly typed foreach iterations in early versions of C# wouldn't be easy.

@mjwills ah that completes the explanation. Thank you!

foreach (IList<string> x in xs)

is not compiled to
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    // (like your second line)
    IList<string> x = enumerator.Current; // Current being IList<double>
}

but to
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    IList<string> x = (IList<string>)enumerator.Current;
}

This is because the compiler will try to help us with an explicit conversion that we haven't explicitly defined (and to be honest we couldn't have due to the brevity of the syntax):

If there is not an explicit conversion (§10.3) from T (the iteration
type) to V (the local_variable_type in the foreach statement), an
error is produced and no further steps are taken.

So it follows that, if there is, it will be put there:
IList<string> x = (IList<string>)enumerator.Current;

According to the 10.3.5 Explicit reference conversions section from the language specification such a conversion is allowed (in our case from IList<double> to IList<string>):

From any interface_type S to any interface_type T, provided S is not
derived from T.

For the second set of examples, there isn't a possible explicit conversion from double to string - so that's why the compiler issues errors there in the foreach part too.
